# Visual Basic listbox with loop to determine a total score and average

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

I am new to `VB` and I need to create a program for a skating rink.  The number of judges varies from week to week and at the end of each skater's routine each judge assigns a score *0-10* to the skater.  The application needs to allow the manger of the rink to enter each judge's score for a specific skater.  It should also calculate and display the `skater's average`, `the number of scores entered`, and the `total score`.  You select each score from a `List box` and then click the `Record Score button`.

I have no idea where to go next.  Everything is incorrect when you select the first score from the `list box` and its also re-adding the score to the bottom of the `list box`.  Below is the code and any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
       Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Fill list box with values

        For intScore As Integer = 0 To 10 Step 1
            lstScore.Items.Add(intScore.ToString)
        Next intScore
        lstScore.SelectedItem = "0"

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRecordScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecordScore.Click
        'accumulates the scores for each skater
        Dim intScore As Integer
        Dim intNumScores As Integer
        Dim intTotalScore As Integer
        Dim decAvgScore As Decimal

        Integer.TryParse(lstScore.SelectedItem.ToString, intScore)

        'add score to score 
        lstScore.Items.Add(lstScore.SelectedItem)

        'update average
        intNumScores = 0
        intTotalScore = 0
        For Each selScore As Object In lstScore.Items
            If Integer.TryParse(selScore.ToString, intScore) Then
                intNumScores = intNumScores + intScore
                intTotalScore = intTotalScore + 1
            End If
        Next
        decAvgScore = intNumScores \ intTotalScore
        lblTotalScore.Text = intNumScores.ToString
        lblNumScores.Text = intTotalScore.ToString
        lblAvgScore.Text = decAvgScore.ToString("N1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNextSkater_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextSkater.Click
        'clears screen, sets focus
        lblTotalScore.Text = String.Empty
        lblNumScores.Text = String.Empty
        lblAvgScore.Text = String.Empty
        lstScore.Focus()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
Public Class Form1
    'Declare TotalScore and NumScore here so they're values stay constant
    Dim intTotalScore As Integer = 0
    Dim intNumScores As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Populate list box with scores
        For intScore As Integer = 0 To 10 Step 1
            lstScore.Items.Add(intScore.ToString)
        Next intScore
        lstScore.SelectedItem = "0"
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRecordScore_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRecordScore.Click
        Dim intScore As Integer
        Dim AvgScore As Decimal

        'add score to score 
        intScore = lstScore.SelectedIndex
        intTotalScore = intTotalScore + lstScore.SelectedIndex

        'update average
        intNumScores = intNumScores + 1
        AvgScore = intTotalScore / intNumScores

        'Populate labels
        lblTotalScore.Text = intTotalScore.ToString
        lblNumScores.Text = intNumScores.ToString
        lblAvgScore.Text = AvgScore.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNextSkater_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNextSkater.Click
        'clears screen, sets focus
        intTotalScore = 0
        intNumScores = 0

        lblTotalScore.Text = String.Empty
        lblNumScores.Text = String.Empty
        lblAvgScore.Text = String.Empty
        lstScore.SelectedItem = "0"
        lstScore.Focus()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Remember that `lstScore.Items.Add(lstScore.SelectedItem)` will only add another item to the listbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Supersnake this did the trick.  I see what I was missing and did incorrectly.  I appreciate the help!